# Firefox loadURI with more than one flag

Tags: firefox-addon, bit-manipulation

Any idea how to use loadURI with more than one flag?

One flag works like that:

```
loadURI(url, nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE, null, null, null);
```

But how to add another one?

Thanks

Comment: That's not how SO works. Even if you found your answer, leave the question up to help others out. Plus, since you did find the answer, you can answer your own question!

Answer (score 1):

Just OR the flags together:

```
var flags = nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE | nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_HISTORY;
loadURI(url, flags, null, null, null);
```